# New restricted user on VPS : need to reinstall everything?

Tags: linux, bash, vps

I'm deploying my NodeJs website on VPS and follow tutorial from my hosting services like this :

https://docs.ovh.com/au/en/vps/tips-for-securing-a-vps/

I created a "safe user" with restricted rights but when I do :

```
safeuser@vps:~/app$ npm init
-bash: npm: command not found
safeuser@vps:~/app$ pm2 list
-bash: pm2: command not found
```

Do I need to reinstall NPM, PM2 etc. for my SafeUser ? I'm new to sysadmin...

For the path :

```
debian@vps:~$ type npm
npm is hashed (/home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/bin/npm)
```

And then :

```
safeuser@vps:~/app$ /home/debian/.nvm/versions/node/v15.12.0/bin/npm init
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Sounds like a path variable issue, use the entire path to npm

Comment: Please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1644261/edit) your post with new data, rather than putting them in comments.

Answer (score 2):

You installed Node using NVM (Node Version Manager). That means it's indeed local to the user.

NVM is great for development, but not so great for production deployments. Instead, you should install the Debian package for the Node version you need: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md

It will then be available for all users and can easily be kept up-to-date with the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Many cloud virtual private servers providers require you to specifically request root user access, or at the very least login in as root to create an account with sudoers access.  I suggest looking through more documentation from your provider, or just calling their support for guidance.